Is there a “longest-tailed” probability distribution?
I’ve often heard folks use the term “long-tailed distribution” informally to refer to a probability distribution in which a lot of the probability mass is concentrated far from the mean. That got me wondering if there is a single probability distribution with the “longest tail,” in the sense that the maximum amount of probability mass is far from the mean.
To make this rigorous, let’s pin down some requirements. We’ll have $p : \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ be a function over nonnegative real numbers. We’ll require the following:

$\int_0^\infty{p(x) dx} = 1$ ($p$ is a probability mass function).
$p$ is nonincreasing. This ensures that the distribution shape is one where there really is a “tail,” rather than having several peaks far from the origin.
$p$ is continuous. This ensures we’re looking at “nicely-shaped” functions rather than discrete stairsteps.
For all $t$, the quantity $\int_0^t{p(x) dx}$ is minimal across all such functions. This ensures that the greatest amount of probability mass is far from the origin.

Is there a single pmf $p$ meeting these criteria? If so, how do we prove it? If not, how do we prove that for every such $p$ there’s a $p’$ that is “longer-tailed” according to the last metric?
Thanks!

Hint:  $p'(s) = 2 p(2s)$, or the reverse $p'(s) = p(s/2)/2$.

@GEdgar Can you elaborate on what you’re proposing? I have a general background in mathematics but am not used to proving statements about the best functions of a particular type and could use some more detailed guidance. Thanks!

If $p(x)$ is any probability density function, then $p'(s) := p(s/2)/2$ is another probability density function with longer tail than $p$.

@GEdgar Oh, sorry, I thought $p’$ was the derivative of $p$. Convert your comment to an answer?

What GEdgar proposes is rescaling the $p(x)$. Surely, that is not what the OP is looking for.

@M.Wind Perhaps I’m mistaken, but GEdgar’s answer seems to indicate that there can’t be a longest-tailed distribution because any such distribution could be stretched into a longer one. If that’s the case, that would be a sufficient negative answer to the question.

@templatetypedef Yes, every probability density function can be rescaled so that it becomes broader. But that is a trivial property. It says nothing about the intrinsic properties of the function. You should define a measure to distinguish between candidate functions; a measure which is independent of scaling.

@M.Wind Good point. I think that’s a good one for a follow-up question.

@templatetypedef In my opinion $f(x) = \exp(-x^\alpha)$ is a good candidate function. With $\alpha$ a small positive number. It is a monotonically decreasing function, very broad, but it can be normalized and its moments exist. And of course it can be rescaled if so desired.

If $p(x)$ is any probability density function, then $q(s) := p(s/2)/2$ is another probability density function with longer tail than $p$.
